# splitting comma separated ignores last item

Tags: java, string, split

When I try to split a String value   `",,1,"`   it returns an array of size three instead of four. How can I correct it?

code:

```
    String values= ",,1,";
    values.split(",");
```

returns:

```
    [0]=""
    [1]=""
    [2]=1
```

Comment: use `values.split(",", -1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it, then use a negative `limit`

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
     String values= ",,1,";
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values.split(",", -1)));
}
```

O/P :

```
[, , 1, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
String values= ",,1,";
String[] val =  values.split(",", -1);
```

Two argument version of `String.split(String regex, int limit)`

> If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied
>   at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Here is javadoc reference of this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

That only happens when the seperator symbol is at the end of the string

```
if (values.charAt(values.length()-1) == ',')
    // Do something here
```

just check if the last character is your seperator symbol...

Answer (score 0):

```
String values= ",,1,";
values.split(",",values.length());
```

You can try this